# How to exclude base url from some rewrite rule in htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey everyone I have a rewrite rule in .htaccess file which is

```
RewriteRule  ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)?$  product.php?product=$1    [NC,L]
```

When I go to www.domain.com it apply the above rule and redirect to product.php and when www.domain.com/index.php it works fine. Where I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `?` in your regex which is making whole pattern optional and exclude directories from this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?product=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /your_project_folder_name/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```